# Determine when a comma is required for json key/value in a ruby loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord

I'm using an each loop to output validation errors for my comments model into simple JSON key value pairs. The problem I face is that I can't have a trailing comma after the last string, because jQuery doesn't like dodgy JSON.

```
{
<% @comment.errors.each do |field, msg| %>
  "<%= field.downcase %>": "<%= msg %>",
<% end %>
}
```

The code above outputs fine, but it will add a comma to the last `"<%= msg %>"` which causes the JSON to fail when it's parsed.

I've tried using `.each_with_index`, but I can't get it to work with `|field, msg, index|` - so unless you know how to get that to work, it's off the cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-join)

```
 <%= @comment.errors.map{|k,v| "'#{k.downcase}' : '#{msg}'"}.join(",") %>
```

But won't simply `@comments.errors.to_json` work?

PS: To make `each_with_index`: work with hash:

```
 hash.each_with_index do |(key,value), index|
     #code code
 end
```

Comment: Thanks tihom, yes I could use `@comment.errors.to_json`, but there's custom strings within this JSON output that aren't associated with the `@comment` instance.

Comment: Also thanks for the tip on each_with_index, that's very handy.

Comment: Another issue is that `to_json` groups messages into arrays, like `"topic":["is not included in the list","can't be blank"]` and map + join make them separate entries.

Comment: Isn't that meant to be `.map{|k,v|}`? (not `k.v`)